# What is the magnification of the stock lens used in Rpicam V2?

Tags: hardware, raspicam, picamera

I'm trying to get the overall optical magnification of my digital microscope and wondered if the lens built in the Rpicam v2 has any magnification. Does anyone know this specification? Thanks!

Comment: Have you done any reseache, I can't see that ?

Comment: perhaps this question IS the research :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no information, but here is other info you may found helpful:

crop factor is: **9.406**
focal length: **28.6 mm** (full frame equivalent).

My personal experience show such lens usually have between 1:5 and 1:10 magnification ration (1 on the lens is 5 on the real object). There is relatively simple way to calculate the magnification: put rules under the microscope, make a photo and calculate the size of object on the sensor and real object size.

[Here](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html) you can find some of the specs of this module sensor.

Comment: for that, you have to know the size of the camera sensor

Comment: @jsotola, correct. Added link to specs :)